# Jquery tablesorter generates error in custom parser for type text when input is numeric

Tags: jquery, parsing, tablesorter

I have a simple tablesorter in which I have written my own parser for a column. On the PhP side, I generate a data attribute whose value is used as the sort value for the cell. My problem is that in the custom parser, when I return the Data-... value, it gives me an error on an integer value, when type specified for the custom parser is text. One would normally expect such errors the other way around. The error on the console generated by tablesorter.js is

```
        Uncaught TypeError: Object 11 has no method 'replace'
```

Where 11 is the numeric value assigned to data-skaddress attribute of the cell.

```
 $.tablesorter.addParser({
    id: 'skaddress',
    is: function(s) {
      return false;
    },
    format: function(s, table, cell, cellIndex) {
      return $(cell).data('skaddress');  
    },
    type: 'text'  // <<<<-------- If this is changed to 'numeric', all is well
 });
```

In other words, if I have a numeric value assigned to data-skaddress attibute of the cell   it fails when I think that 'text' type simply means that any string, including all digits, would be considered a text field. The HTML markup of the cell generating the error is:

```
        <td  data-ssipaddress="11">12.29.14.97.190.111</td>
```

Any way around this? Spent a lot of time trying to find a real solution. Of course, there are workarounds. I can, for example, always generate a fixed alphabet before the long numeric string on the PhP side. The reason that I need a text field and not a numeric field is because my strings consist of long series of digits though in the example I am using only two digit strings.

Please do not ask me to use Datatables instead. I like tablesorter (the one maintained by Mottie?) as it is light weight and great for what I need and infact I think better than Datatables in some aspect. It took me some time to get a hang of it. Just this unexpected problem...

**Update:** It works if a leading zero is placed before the string of digits assigned to data- attribute!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between 555 and "555".

You must make sure that your value is a string when you pass it. You can assure that by:

```
foo = foo + "";
```

if foo is your value.

Comment: Yes. Thanks for the help. Your suggestion works but can you enlighten me on this: When I return $(cell).data('skaddress') am I not returning the string-value of the data attribute data-skaddress? So, why do I need a further step to expressly convert it to string again?

Comment: That is a good question. In fact you are returning the value of the 'skaddress' attribute and whether it is integer or string is decided by several factors: your browser, jQuery version/implementation, the actual value of the attribute. Given the fact that in your case it was an integer we can safely conclude that it can be an integer if we believe our own eyes.

Comment: I thought later that it could also be that the consumer (the function or method in tablesorter here) may have its own code which reads the value, decides the type and does some internal assignment which results in the error. Strangely, a leading zero also works! I guess it must be the tablesorter code's logic. Thanks a lot... I spent a lot of time on trying to fix this until I got your workaround.

Comment: You are welcome. The leading zero and the workaround in this answer work for the same reason: you convert your value to a string. I believe this solution is more elegant, because there is no chance of damaging the integrity of your data by adding an empty string to your value, but in some cases a leading zero might be feasible as well.